# Google Play Console doesn't accept YouTube Shorts?

Tags: google-play-console

I want to post a demo video on my store listing which is 25 seconds long but everytime I upload to youtube it then classifies it as a short then when I use that shorts link as my video link for my store listing Google Play Console doesn't accept it.

Has anybody else faced this problem? And do you know of any workarounds?

I tried to reupload to youtube but it always classifies it as a short